# Read text data into R

Tags: r, parsing, import, while-loop, metadata

I have a list of items in a single vector itemlist file identified by a single integer. I also have a meta-data on each item. In this case the item is a book on Amazon.com, and the meta data is on various attributes as listed below. For each book on my itemlist, I'd like get the its title, group, sales rank, and a few others. The metadata contains data for other groups, like DVD, but I don't need those and would like to skip them. In the metadata file, each item and its attributes start with "ID: " and ends with an empty row. I've tried a bunch of tools in R without much success. And was hoping someone can help.

Here's an excerpt from the metadata file, for 2 books (ID: 9, and ID: 10).

```
Id:   9
ASIN: 1859677800
  title: Making Bread: The Taste of Traditional Home-Baking
  group: Book
  salesrank: 949166
  similar: 0
  categories: 1
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Cooking, Food & Wine[6]|Baking[4196]|Bread[4197]
  reviews: total: 0  downloaded: 0  avg rating: 0

Id:   10
ASIN: 0375709363
  title: The Edward Said Reader
  group: Book
  salesrank: 220379
  similar: 5  039474067X  0679730672  0679750541  1400030668  0896086704
  categories: 3
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Literature & Fiction[17]|History & Criticism[10204]|Criticism & Theory[10207]|General[10213]
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Nonfiction[53]|Politics[11079]|History & Theory[11086]
   |Books[283155]|Subjects[1000]|Nonfiction[53]|Social Sciences[11232]|Anthropology[11233]|Cultural[11235]
  reviews: total: 6  downloaded: 6  avg rating: 4
    2000-10-8  cutomer: A2RI73IFW2GWU1  rating: 4  votes:  12  helpful:   7
    2001-5-4  cutomer: A1GE54WF2WUZ2X  rating: 5  votes:  11  helpful:   8
    2001-8-27  cutomer: A36S399V1VC4DR  rating: 4  votes:   5  helpful:   3
    2002-1-26  cutomer: A280GY5UVUS2QH  rating: 3  votes:  12  helpful:   7
    2004-4-7  cutomer: A2YHZJIU4L4IOI  rating: 4  votes:  10  helpful:   2
    2004-4-27  cutomer: A1MB83EO48TRSC  rating: 4  votes:   5  helpful:   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data posted is in a text file named `myfile.txt`, reduce it to just those lines that are ok to use and then parse that to produce the long form data.  Add a `grp` column which identifies fields from the same Id.  Optionally use `dcast` in the reshape2 package to reshape it from long to wide form:

```
library(reshape2)

L <- readLines("myfile.txt")

# add other fields to the regular expression as needed
ok <- grep("^Id:|^ *title:|^ *group:", L, value = TRUE)

# create data frame in long form
long <- data.frame(lab = gsub("^ *|:.*", "", ok), value = sub("^.*?: ", "", ok))
long$grp <- cumsum(long$lab == "Id")

# optionally reshape it into wide form
wide <- dcast(grp ~ lab, data = long)
```

The last line gives:

```
> wide
  grp group   Id                                title
1   1  Book    9 The Taste of Traditional Home-Baking
2   2  Book   10               The Edward Said Reader
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `readLines` you can get these data into R as long character strings:

```
z <- readLines("example-text.txt")
```

You could then use this initial read in to separately read in each record using `scan` or to split that record into rows. For example:

```
idpos <- grep("Id",z)
scan("example-text.txt", skip=idpos[1]-1, nlines=idpos[2]-idpos[1], what="character",sep="\n")
scan("example-text.txt", skip=idpos[2]-1, nlines=length(z)-idpos[2], what="character",sep="\n")
```

You can then parse those strings in various ways to turn them into another data structure.